# Инверсия бита в числе

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Как инвертировать 4-й бит в числе?

```
a=165; a=~a<<4
```

Правильно?

Comment: в zsh: `a=$((a ^ 0b1000))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(( a ^ 0x10 ))
```

или, для наглядности (спасибо @mkkik):

```
$(( a ^ 1 << 4 ))
$(( a ^ (1 << 4) ))
```

`^` - операция побитового исключительного "или" (переключатель, иными словами); 0x10 - четвёртый бит, если считать самый младший нулевым. Во втором варианте приоритет сдвига `<<` выше, чем `^`: сначала выполнится сдвиг, а потом переключение флага. Поэтому скобки необязательны, но улучшают восприятие.

Comment: Можно `0x10` заменить на `1 << 4`, чтобы очевиднее была связь с битовой позицией.